# Leaking valve connection, recent shower install

Tags: shower, leak

Shower is on second floor, I noticed wet spots in first floor ceiling. I opened the shower trim and found the drip on the left copper connection to the valve. I shut down water in the house.

I assume that pipe needs to be reinstalled to the valve and thus I need to remove the tile.

I want to ask perhaps there are better methods to fix it.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can the valve be access from the backside of the wall?

Comment: Yes it can by cutting the drywall in the hallway

Comment: How recent? Did you hire someone to do this or was it a DIY?

Comment: I hired someone 2 months ago. He did tile and copper connections to the new valve.

Comment: I'd be calling him back and showing him the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely look at cutting an access into the drywall instead of removing tile. You'd have to remove a lot of tile to get in there and redo that connection. Dry wall is easy to fix. You should frame it in afterwards for access in the future. Just make absolutely sure you know where the water is leaking from. It could be another location and pooling at the point you see it. If the installer has a guarantee, I'd be getting him back there. good luck and stay safe out there.

Comment: Yes, the "someone" needs to come back and repair the leak,  Repair should be through a cutout in the drywall.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think it is possible to reheat the connection through the tile opening and apply more solder wire?

Comment: I personally have never had any luck  trying to reheat a connection and add more solder. I think it had something to do with not being able to get the flux deep in the joint.  Even  if it worked, for how long?